# Run .SAS en bath mode - Linux

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

We are trying to run a SAS project (.SAS). This project internally queries a library, but every time we have tried it via batch, it says that the library is not assigned, which is completely incorrect because it is indeed assigned.

The command we are using is as follows:

sas -nodms -batch -sysin Project.sas

Internally in .sas, it queries a table:

FROM Name.name_table

The error it indicates is:

ERROR: Libref Name is not assigned.

Would it be necessary to make any call to the library or its location before running the project?

Comment: What does the log say at the line where your LIBNAME statement is that is defining the libref of NAME?

Comment: So there could be a few things going on here. One is a user has their own personal startup code executing before they start their program that may assign a library automatically. This wouldn't be captured in batch. The other option is Project.sas does not have a libname statement to assign a library. The third is that the libname statement is failing to assign for some reason. Either way, the log should give you a really good idea on what's happening.

Comment: This is how the libraries are assigned in the .sas file /* Assignment of the library for SASApp.T */
;
/* Assignment of the library for SASApp.LIB_T */
;

Comment: Those appear to be comments without SAS code. A library assignment looks like this: `libname foo <options or location here>`;

Comment: If this process is scheduled with the batch server from the SAS Management Console, it's not necessary to declare the location of the library, which is why the .sas project doesn't include it.

Our issue arises when we attempt to execute the project from the server; it fails to locate the libraries. The command we use to execute the .sas file is: sas -nodms -batch -sysin Project.sas

Comment: Ah, that probably explains it. Let me know if I am understanding this correctly. If you schedule through the metadata server, it works. If you're on the server, not connected to the metadata server, and running the sas command, it does not. When you're running the sas executable, it's just running SAS in its own fully independent session. It's not connected to the Metadata server which can assign metalibs automatically. You'll have to connect to the metadata server to assign metadata libraries. Enterprise Guide does this for you automatically, which is why they see the automatic libraries.